# Pika and gevent - compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, gevent, pika

is Pika compatible with gevent?

Monkey patching provided with gevent patch standard socket library - is this enough for valid switching pika with gevent?

Best regards,
Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monkey-patching pika using gevent should work fine, but it isn't officially supported.

Keep in mind that that pika is not thread-safe, and using gevent won't change that. You still need one pika connection per thread.

There are a couple of threads discussing the usage of gevent and pika on github that might be worth reading through.
https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/102

There is also an currently un-merged pull request open to add a gevent adapter.
https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/860

Comment: What you think - should I use this adapter from PR?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I would just go ahead and use it as-is and monkey patch.

Comment: For what it is worth, I was not able to get things working with Pika 1.2.0 and monkey-patching (gevent 21.1.2) on Windows. I would get errors like "[WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately". On the other hand, monkey-patched Py-AMQP 5.0.6 worked out-of-the-box.